# Why should C++ permit a variable name and a class name to be the same?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   

using namespace std; 

typedef int UINT4;

class Hack
{};

Hack& operator <(Hack& a , Hack& b) 
{
    std::cerr << "1";  
    return a; 
}

Hack& operator >(Hack& a, Hack& b)
{
    std::cerr <<  "2";    
    return a; 
}

int main()
{
    Hack vector; // It SHOULD be OK!?
    Hack UINT4; // It SHOULD be OK!?
    Hack v;
    Hack Hack; // It SHOULD be OK!?
    Hack = v; // It SHOULD be OK!?

    // Please stop to think for a moment: What will the following output?
    vector<UINT4> v; 

    // Oh, my god! The whole world goes mad!

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @xmllimx: Yes no question ;-)

Comment: @RageZ, I know all of the above are legal in C++. But they really make me confused. Why does the C++ standard not explicitly prohibit such naming?

Comment: While it seems amgiguous to the reader, there are actually no syntactic ambiguities whatsoever, so the compiler can compile the code in a way that is well-defined. I would guess that guarding against this kind of naming would cause longer compiletimes, so it was omitted from the standard.

Comment: @Cam, Maybe the C++ standard think it's the responsibility of the programmer not to name as such.

Comment: @xmlimx: maybe because the compiler can handles it, but let's say C/C++ is an old language and really low level so you can write a lot of crap with it ;-)

Comment: Another possibility is that in some situations the most intuitive name for a variable is the same as the type.

Comment: @Cam, the most intuitive name is a name that differs in case according to some popular naming convention (like `Hack hack;`). Case sensitivity really does a nice job here so we don't need identical names for different things.

Comment: to my eyes, the core problem in the exemple is not at all with typenames, but with the choice of angle brackets for templates syntax while both `>` and `<` where already used as operators. This one indeed raise well known problems (even if compilers behavior is well defined).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ever heard of the [following](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html)? Please look close at the parameter types :)

```
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

What you have shown in your question really isn't too dramatic. You declare a variable name in a local scope, but the type names in your program are in global scope. I will show you some real pervert thing now:

```
int nooo = 0;
int main() {
   int nooo = 0;
}
```

W00t? Why does C++ allow us to create two variables of the same name!?!

Alright, I was kidding. I will now introduce you into the *real* dark sides of messing with duplicate names. Consider what C++ allows us!

```
struct A {
  int A; // noes!
};

A A; // another A!
```

In essence, *this* one is all for C compatibility :)

Comment: There's nothing dramatic or interesting about your two-variable example. Unless you were being sarcastic?

Comment: your examples are very illustrative and convincing.

Comment: Actually the first example is trivial: you don't want your local code to break because someone added a variable in the outer scope.

Comment: @ybungalobill exactly my point :) Same holds for the code in question :)

Answer (score 6):

You're asking the question from the point of view or someone who very well *knows* that he is using a class name as a variable identifier : obviously, this isn't a best practice.

Now, let's take it the other way around : suppose you have no idea that there is a weird `typedef int i;` in some obscure header file you are including. Would you expect it to break the following innocent code ?

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: This is a good point, although if the library you're using does things like change `i` to `int` behind your back, you're probably doing it wrong :)

Comment: This one is very different. It does not break the code at all as the code won't compile (and say why). The OP code was perfectly legal C++ that could be very surprising for an innocent reader. But in a way you have a point, the slightest change in the OP code will make it turn into compiler error.